# what are some of the methods to do divergent/convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have no problem with integration finding volumes, surface area and such. But the whole series / sequence chapters completely throw me off, I have no idea where to even begin with problems given. What is the strategy for dealing with series/sequences?

for example, I don't even know where to begin with this one:

\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\ln{n}}} \end{equation}

Comment: Here is another post about the series you mentioned: [The convergence of this series: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^{\log n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1686630).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular series, we can use the comparison test.  For all $n > 7$, we have:

$$\frac{1}{n^{\ln(n)}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$

And so:

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{\ln(n)}} < \sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$

As far as series in general, I find that the most frequently used tests are the integral test, comparison test, alternating series test, and the ratio test.  In general, determining the convergence of series is similar to evaluating integrals.  That is, it takes a lot of practice to develop some intuition.  There is no real formula.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is discouraging, but basically the strategy is: trial and error.  You need to know things like the comparison test, ratio test, root test, integral test, alternating series test and any others you come across, but there is no definitive answer for which one to use in any particular case.  A couple of suggestions:

- if the term $a_n$ includes factorials, the ratio test may be worth a try;
- for rational functions the comparison test (perhaps in the limit form) might be good.

You also need to know the comparative rates of growth of various functions, starting with things like
$$\hbox{constant}<\ln n<n^\alpha<a^n<n!$$
for large $n$.

For the specific example you have asked, just note that $\ln n>2$ for $n\ge8$ and then use a comparison test.

Comment: +1. Learn lots of little tricks, lots of common divergent/convergent series, and try them all out. With practice you'll be able to more quickly spot what trick to use.

Answer (score -1):

Comparison test can be used. Since $\ln n > 2$ for $n\ge 9$ it follows $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}<\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}$, which is a convergente series.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It *partially* answer the question, to be fair.