# The convergence of this series: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^{\log n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came across a problem on convergence of series and I did not get into any idea about this -- any help or hints ? 
 $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^{\log n}}$$

What about $n^{\log(\log n)}$ ?

Comment: Making a guess as to what you mean, Baby Rudin 3.28-3.29 would seem helpful.

Comment: To show divergence if $a\le 1$, it is enough (why?) to show divergence when $n=1$. For this use the Integral Test.

Comment: Hello can you make it clear that my question is about n power logn

Comment: For some $N$, $n>N\implies\log(n)>1$. For some other $N$, $n>N\implies\log(\log(n))>1$.

Comment: Can you edit the problem with n power to the logn please i am not able to do so

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding your notation.

Comment: See also: [Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^∞\frac1{k^{\ln k}}$ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821136)

Answer (score 1):

For which $a$ does
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^a}
$
converge?
For which $a$ does it diverge?

If this converges,
then
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^a\log n}$
will certainly converge
(do you see why?).

Answer (score 1):

Since the series is a positive one and the general term's sequence is monotonically decreasing to zero, you can use [Cauchy's Condensation Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyCondensationTest.html), and:

$$\frac{2^n}{(2^n)^{\log2^n}}=\frac{2^n}{2^{n^2\log2}}=\frac1{2^{n\left(n\log2-1\right)}}\le\frac1{2^n}$$

Comment: Aaaa that is there . Thanks .

Comment: Thank you to anyone who downvoted/upvoted this. It would really help me if anyone who downvoted could be please kind enough to write down the reason: is something wrong, or unclear? I try to learn of my mistakes...if I recognize them.