# Does the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}$  converge or diverge?

The summation is between $n=1$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Eventually, $\ln n>2$, and then $1/n^{\ln n}< 1/n^2$.

Comment: See also: [Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^∞\frac1{k^{\ln k}}$ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821136) and [The convergence of this series: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^{\log n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1686630).

Answer (score 2):

Use $\ln n>2$ then
$$\sum \dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}}<\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: I get caught too, it is actually $n^{\ln(n)}$ not a product.

Comment: I was surprised with other answer which upvoted and I was thinking what happend!

Answer (score 2):

Expounding on MyGlasses's answer:
$ \quad \ln n > 2 \quad \iff \quad n>7 \quad $ as $\quad e^2 > 7$

This implies that $$\frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}<\frac{1}{n^2} \iff n\geq 8$$

So 
$$\begin{align}
\sum _{n=8} ^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}} < \sum_{n=8} ^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\left(\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}\right)
\\
&\approx \frac{\pi^2}{6}-1.51179705215
\end{align}$$

Thus convergent by the direct comparison test.

All while

$$\begin{align}
\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\ln n}}&=\frac{1}{1^{\ln 1}}+ \frac{1}{2^{\ln 2}}+ \frac{1}{3^{\ln 3}}+ \frac{1}{4^{\ln 4}}+ \frac{1}{5^{\ln 5}}+ \frac{1}{6^{\ln 6}}+ \frac{1}{7^{\ln 7}}+\sum _{n=8} ^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}}
\\
&\approx 2.20196513364 +\sum _{n=8} ^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}}
\\
&≲2.20196513364 + \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1.51179705215\right)=2.33510214833
\end{align}
$$