# Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^∞\frac1{k^{\ln k}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{\ln k}}.$$

I have some problems with this sum, I have tried most of the common methods, such as the ratio/root test, integral test, etc. I do believe it looks like a problem easily solvable by a direct comparison with some p-series, however, I do not know how to formulate the inequality.

I did try using the common fact that $\ln(x) \ll x^p$ for large $x$ but that of course only bounds it from below with a convergent series saying nothing about ours. Also I tried rewriting the 'summand' as $e^{\ln(k^{\ln k})}=e^{\ln k \cdot \ln k}$ but this did not really yield anything.

Any answer or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also: [The convergence of this series: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n^{\log n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1686630)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**
Notice that for $k\ge 3$, it is true that $\ln(k)\gt 1$.

Comment: ah, that's better :P

Comment: @qbert Bah, but Cauchy Condensation is *cooler* than the comparison test.

Comment: I do sort of blindly use it when i see an expression like this

Comment: Hmm, so is my thought process correct lin this way, $\frac{1}{3^{ln(3)}}+\frac{1}{4^{ln(4)}}+\frac{1}{5^{ln(5)}}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot$ $\leq \frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2} \cdot \cdot \cdot$ ?

Comment: @Sindbad Haha, well you have the right idea... you can't really put the infinite series in an inequality until you show that it converges, but yeah. Showing that each term of a series (given that they're positive) is less than each term of a converging series proves that the former converges.

Comment: I meant more that you bound it from above, that is that from some large value of k we find that $ln(k) > 2 $, for that k we know that the p-series $\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2}$ is larger since the reciprocals of the latter start getting larger. Is this fair to say?

Comment: @Sindbad Yes, by the comparison test.

Comment: Then I get it! Thanks mate! :)

Comment: @Sindbad Okay, great! Glad to help! Perhaps once you learn the Cauchy Condensation test, this would be a good exercise to try using qbert's method.

Comment: Yes, however it looks quite daunting to me, but I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By the Cauchy-condensation test, the given series converges if and only if the following series converges
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n\frac{1}{(2^{n})^{n\ln 2}}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^{n^2\ln2}}
$$

Comment: This is a bit above me at the moment, I haven't read about the Cauchy-condensation test.

Comment: that's ok, it is however a useful and actually not that hard to prove criteria. I would go with the other answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

For $k > e^2$ we have  $\ln(k) > 2 $ and  $ k^{\ln(k)} > k^2 $

$$ \frac{1}{k^{\ln(k)}} < \frac {1}{k^2} \quad \rightarrow  \sum_k \,\frac{1}{k^{\ln(k)}} < \infty $$

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I did this but not so explicitly :) Thanks